# Basis for a subspace Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\{\,v_1,v_2\,\}$ is a basis for a subspace $V$ show that $\{\,v_1+v_2,v_1−v_2\,\}$ is also a basis for $V$ .

I know that we must have to prove that $v_1+v_2$ and $v_1-v_2$ are linearly independent and they also span $V$ because that is a definition for a basis but am unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t(v_1+v_2)+s(v_1-v_2)=0$ , hence $(t+s)v_1+(t-s)v_2=0$. Since $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is linearly independent, we get $t+s=0$ and $t-s=0$, hence $t=s=0$.

This shows that $\{v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2\}$ is linearly independent.

Since $\dim V=2$, we have that $v_1+v_2,v_1-v_2$ span $V$.

Comment: how does that fact that dim V=2 prove that they span V? can you elaborate?

Comment: There are several charakterisations for basis. One is, that a basis for $V$ is a maximal linear independent set. The set $\{\, v_1+v_2\,\}$ is linear independent. Every linear independet of $V$ set can be enlarged to a basis of $V$. So there is a basis of size $\geq 2$ where those two vectors are a subset. But every basis of $V$ has the same cardinality, which is $2$. So $\{\, v_1+v_2\,\}$ already was a basis.

Comment: @Babelfish I don't understand

Comment: @J-Dorman Which part do you not understand? It is hard to estimate your linear algebra knowledge

Answer (score 0):

To show LI, you need to show that the only linear combination of the vectors $v_1+v_2$ and $v_1-v_2$ that gives the zero vector is the zero combination, i.e. the following equation has ONLY the trivial solution.
$$c_1(v_1+v_2)+c_2(v_1-v_2)=0.$$
This amounts to 
$$(c_1+c_2)v_1+(c_1-c_2)v_2=0.$$
Now $v_1, v_2$ are LI, therefore these coefficients must be $0$. Thus we have
\begin{align*}
c_1+c_2 & = 0\\
c_1-c_2 & = 0.
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that it has only the trivial (zero solution). Hence the new set is LI.

Showing span is easy or you can use the fact that the given subspace is 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several possible arguments:

Set $w_1=v_1+v_2$, $\;w_2=v_1-v_2$.

- As, by  hypothesis, $V$ has dimension $2$, it is enough to prove either that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent (which amounts to showing a linear system has only the trivial solution), or that $v_1, v_2\in \langle w_1,w_2\rangle$.

$\qquad$This second way is easy: form the equations defining $w_1$ and $w_2$, you deduce readily
$$v_1=\tfrac12(w_1+w_2),\quad v_2=\tfrac12(w_1-w_2).$$

- If you know about  determinants, observe the column matrices $\;\begin{bmatrix}v_1\newline v_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\;\begin{bmatrix}w_1\newline w_2\end{bmatrix}$ are linked by the relation
  $$\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\ w_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&\phantom{-}1\\ 1&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\newline v_2\end{bmatrix},$$
  and the matrix $\;A=\begin{bmatrix}1&\phantom{-}1\\ 1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible since $\det A=-2$, so it maps a basis onto a basis.